# Filesystem synchronization library?

Tags: sql-server, backup, filesystems, offsite

I've got 10 GB of files to back up daily to another site. The client is way out in the country so bandwidth is an issue. Does anyone know of any existing software or libraries out there that help with keeping a folder with its files synchronized across a slow link, that is it only sends files across if they have changed? Some kind of hash checking would be nice, too, to at least confirm the two sides are the same.

I don't mind paying some money for it, seeing as how it might take me several weeks to a month to implement something decent on my own. I just don't want to re-invent the wheel, here. BTW it is a windows shop (they have an in house windows IT guy) so windows is preferred.

I also have 10 GB of SQL Server 2000 databases to go across. Is the SQL server replication mode reliable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into rysnc.

Comment: Thanks David, rsync will save me a lot of trouble.

Isaac

Comment: Ended up using deltacopy, which wraps Rsync, thanks again David!

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you're looking for seeing as you're an MS shop
[Microsoft Sync Framework File Synchronization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb887623.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Two more suggestions are [Robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) and [XXCopy](http://www.xxcopy.com/index.htm).